# How to animate removeFromSuperview

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiviewanimation, catransition

I animated the appearance of my subview with:

```
CATransition *transition = [CATransition animation];
transition.duration = 0.3;
transition.type = kCATransitionReveal;
[webView.layer addAnimation:transition forKey:nil];

[self.view addSubview:webView];
```

But now I want to remove my subView. How can I add animation to do this? Like other CATransition? When to add this? Before or after addSubview?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Well you could do the animation first and on the `animationEndListener` call `removeFromSuperView`

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.5
    delay:1.0
    options: UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut
    animations:^{
        yourView.alpha = 0;
    }completion:^(BOOL finished){
        [yourView removeFromSuperview];
    }];
```

Comment: not sure if this has changed, but the option now is: UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut